# Is it according to the "pure doctrine" of OOP to call a method without any in- and output argument but a reference to the object itself?

Tags: matlab, oop

In my example, I have a class representing a certain set of data. Some of the data's properties are written to the class' `properties`, while the class' `methods` mostly perform tasks like reading the raw data from spreadsheets and doing some pre-calculations.
I was wondering if the following is according to the "pure doctrine" of OOP, and if not, if and how it could be syntactically improved.
Here is a very simple (untested) implementation of such a class.

```
classdef dataObjectTest < handle
    properties
        filename char
        pathFilename char
        rawData double
    end
    methods
        function obj = setPathnameFromFilename(obj, filename)
            %setPathnameFromFilename Determine full path- & filename from single filename
            %   filename: Name of the file containing the raw data, e.g., 'Test.xls'
            obj.filename = filename;
            intermed = dir(obj.filename);
            obj.pathFilename = fullfile(intermed.folder, obj.filename);
        end

        function obj = loadRawDataFromSpreadsheet(obj)
            % loadRawDataFromSpreadsheet Convert the raw data stored in a spreadsheet into a Matlab
            % array, using the full path- & filename determined by setPathnameFromFilename
            %   rawData: Array contating the raw data
            obj.rawData = xlsread(obj.pathFilename);
        end
    end
end
```

And here is how one would call this class from another program/script:

```
test = dataObjectTest;
test.setPathnameFromFilename('Test.xls');
test.loadRawDataFromSpreadsheet;
```

I am especially concerned about the third line. Since both input and output arguments of the method `loadRawDataFromSpreadsheet` are properties of the class, it is unnecessary to explicitly define them in the function header. On the other hand, this implementation seems somehow awkward to me and not in "spirit" of OOP, which is a lot about clearly defined interfaces between the user and the class.
So although my code works, I'm still wondering if this is "the right way" to do it or if could be significantly improved.

**UPDATE:** Admittedly, the choice of my methods' names may have been misleading, but this was not the point of the question. So let me try to clarify.

The first method takes the user-given string `filename` and returns `pathFilename`. But since this is also a property of the class, it is not visible from the function signature, i.e., the function should look like:

```
function pathFilename = setPathnameFromFilename(obj, filename)
```

But this doesn't work in Matlab. (The `varName =` part corresponds to `return varName` in other languages.)
The second method returns the array `rawData`, and since the input argument `pathFilename`is, again, a property of the class, neither are visible in the method's signature.
So my concern was about having methods which actually *have* in- and output arguments, but do not reveal them through their signature.

Comment: This is an invalid class file in MATLAB, the variable type declarations are not valid syntax because MATLAB isn't explicitly typed. i.e. you shouldn't have the words `char` or `array` in the first 5 lines of your code.

Comment: @Wolfie that's [100% incorrect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/defining-properties.html#bu5hzp7)

Comment: @excaza Also 100% bizarre then, because I just pasted that code into MATLAB 2015b and got *"Parse error at char: usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax"* with a red underline in the editor, then the error *"'char' is already defined as a property"* when trying to create an object instance. I don't want to argue with the docs, it seems a sensible feature, but I can't run that code!

Comment: @Wolfie the property syntax [changed from `@` to a space](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-class-property-types-2) in R2016a. Things can change quite a bit in 2 years.

Comment: @excaza Ah thanks, would be nice to be able to rely on *documented MATLAB* for core functionality changes like this! I use 2015b for compatibility with large systems at work exactly *because* of the large changes between releases. Had never written classes with this syntax in 2017b which I also use. Maybe I was just 80% incorrect heh, worth noting the difference for future readers.

Comment: By editing your question's code, you have nullified 50% of Stephan's  answer and part of Sam's answer. It would be better to leave your question as it was so that the page makes sense for future readers.

Comment: The original version is still available through the `edited` hyperlink. Unfortunately, my imprecise naming choices seemed to distract from the actual core of the question, which I tried to clarify in the latest edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically fine, but I'd implement it like this:

```
classdef dataObjectTest < handle
    properties
        filename char
        pathname char
        rawData array
    end
    methods    
        function loadRawDataFromSpreadsheet(obj, filename)
            obj.filename = filename;
            obj.pathname = dataObjectTest.extractPathName(filename
            obj.rawData = xlsread(obj.pathname);
        end
    end
    methods (Static, Access = private)
        function pathname = extractPathName(filename)
            intermed = dir(filename);
            pathname = fullfile(intermed.folder, filename);
        end
    end
end
```

Notes:

1. Since it's a handle object, you don't need `obj` as an output argument of the main method.
2. I've moved the extraction of the path to a private static method, as it's really a utility function (you could instead implement as an actual subfunction rather than a method).
3. I've renamed the main method to start with `load` rather than `get`, to make sure it isn't mistaken for a property get method.

I wouldn't worry too much about the "spirit of OOP" - instead, just make sure your code works, is well-organised, is testable, and maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

It is just fine according to the "doctrine" of pure OOP for a method to have no `in` or `out` parameters apart from the object reference.

However, what you are doing doesn't conform to normal practice for method naming.  A method with a name starting with `get` is normally a "getter".  The primary purpose of a "getter" is to *return* some component of the class.  Generally speaking, a "getter" should not modify the target object.

But you have two `get...` methods that 1) modify the target object and 2) don't return anything.

In my opinion:

- the first one should be named `setPathnameFromFilename` or maybe just `setFilename`.
- the second one should be named `loadRawDataFromSpreadsheet` or something like that.

> On the other hand, this implementation seems somehow awkward to me and not in "spirit" of OOP, which is a lot about clearly defined interfaces between the user and the class.

I actually don't see that at all.  Sure, the interface is not clearly defined, but that is largely because you have not documented the methods *and* because you have chosen (IMO) misleading / non-informative class and method names.

(Disclaimer: I am a Java programmer.  However, the basic principles of OOP are largely the same for all OO languages.)

Comment: For what it's worth, in MATLAB you can also call an object's method by passing it as the first argument, avoiding dot notation all together: i.e. `getRawDataFromSpreadsheet(test)` is equivalent to `test.getRawDataFromSpreadsheet`. That's why the object is always the first argument in the actual function definition. Your assessments definitely hold for OOP in MATLAB though.